# What is difference between ST_DWithin and ST_Distance for proximity search in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, spatial-query

I have records stored in a table with latitude/longitude coordinates stored in a geometry field.  I want to find all records nearby a user supplied reference point.  Note "nearby" probably means less than 100km (possibly even smaller).

Most examples I see use `ST_DWithin`. Is there a reason you can't use `ST_Distance`? What is the difference between using `ST_DWithin` and `ST_Distance` to do this?

For example:

```
SELECT name, ST_AsText(coords)
FROM places
WHERE ST_DWithin(coords, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-12.5842 24.4944)',4326), 1)
```

vs

```
SELECT name, ST_AsText(coords)
FROM places
WHERE ST_Distance(coords, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-12.5842 24.4944)',4326)) < 1
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ST_Distance` is a calculation which must be executed and evaluated on every row.  `ST_DWithin` can use an index, so it's likely to be *much* faster.

Note that you really ought to be using a `geography` cast, so instead of Cartesian degrees (which are useless) a geodesic ground distance could be specified:

```sql
SELECT name, ST_AsText(coords)
FROM   places
WHERE  ST_DWithin(coords::geography, 
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-12.5842 24.4944)',4326)::geography,
            100000) -- 100km in meters
```

Comment: Also managed to find this which says pretty much same thing: http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin

Comment: Updated link for my above comment (old link giving a 404): https://postgis.net/documentation/tips/st-dwithin/