# Finding list of points near current long/lat using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, st-distance

[UPDATE]

What I have now is light years better than I did before.
With the suggestion to look at ST_POINT, I restarted my googling and the query looks now like so:

```
SELECT "ID" from "CityBottle".message_locations where location= "CityBottle"."fnMakePoint"( :Longitude,:Latitude)
```

MakePoint is a function defined like so:

```
BEGIN
 RETURN CAST(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(Longitude, Latitude),4326) As geography);
END;
```

It is worth noting that I did notice the function ST_MAKEPOINT, but I am at the prototype stage right now and the above was good enough (plus, I would probably still wrap that into a custom function to protect the queries...).

Now, the main contention I have is "how do I define a reasonable index"?
I mean, the points are in their own table and I am accessing the whole thing via a view to list the messages (the table has a query only to make sure that the point isn't already in the table...).

Thus, I'll need some kind of index that will work properly so that I can use ST_DWithin.

Can I just create an index on the field? Is there anything specific I need to do for better performance?

[ORIGINAL]

What I need is a "where am I?" kind of thing listing points within a certain radius from the current POINT(long,lat) .

My understanding is that you do this with ST_DISTANCE and saying that it has to be, for example, less than a certain amount.

My first attempt has been this:

```
select* from "CityBottle".message_locations ml where ST_DISTANCE(ml.location,POINT(12.0,13,0)) < 100
```

which has yielded this error message:

```
ERROR:  function point(numeric, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...essage_locations ml where ST_DISTANCE(ml.location,POINT(12.0...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried with 'ST_Point' ?
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html

Comment: Oh! No, I didn't realise that was a thing :) Will try right now.

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer? I will accept it :)

Comment: You're not really ready for an answer yet,  because you have **several** serious SQL errors that need to be fixed. 1) cossing the native and PostGIS geometry types, 2) Not using ST_SetSRID to establish your GCS, 3) not casting to `geography` to make the `ST_Distance` operate in geodetic units, and 4) Failure to use the spatial index by using the `ST_DWithin` function. This question is likely a duplicate of a number of similar questions. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79961/what-is-difference-between-st-dwithin-and-st-distance-for-proximity-search-in-po

Comment: I wish i could say that you are entirely correct... but I can't, because the ST_POINT pointed me to the right "rabbit hole" to explore. I will update the original post with my findings.