# Select points within a buffer / radius of a point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, knn

When a user click on a map, I first want to get closest point (placename), then use that point to get number of points (schools) within 10km buffer / radius

```
... 
$str = pg_query($conn, "SELECT ST_Buffer(a.geom, 1000) as buffer, a.*, s.*, ST_Distance(a.geom, r.ref_geom) AS distance FROM placenames a CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_MakePoint($coordinate)::geography AS ref_geom) AS r INNER JOIN local s ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, s.geom) WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, r.ref_geom, '$radius') ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.geom, r.ref_geom)"


if(pg_num_rows($str) > 0){
    $area = $fetch['placename'];
    $buffer = $fetch['buffer'];
    //How do I use this buffer and get all schools within that buffer
}
```

3 dots means there is a code on top

Comment: Never use `ST_Distance` or `ST_Buffer` in a distance search query. Instead use `ST_DWithin`, which can use an index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between ST\_DWithin and ST\_Distance for proximity search in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79961/what-is-difference-between-st-dwithin-and-st-distance-for-proximity-search-in-po)

Comment: This is wonderful thanks but how do I join the 2nd table

Answer (score 5):

Get the closest geometry to a given input geometry - referred to as *(spatial) (K)NN* search - over `GEOGRAPHY`s casted on-the-fly:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  <table> AS t
ORDER BY
  t.geom::GEOGRAPHY <-> <input_geom>::GEOGRAPHY
LIMIT
  1
;
```

Get all geometries in proximity to an input geometry:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  <table> AS t
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(t.geom::GEOGRAPHY, <input_geom>::GEOGRAPHY, <radius_in_meter>)
;
```

---

As combo, using an inline sub-query:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  <table> AS t
WHERE
  ST_DWithin(
    t.geom::GEOGRAPHY,
    (
      SELECT
        _t.geom::GEOGRAPHY
      FROM
        <table> AS _t
      ORDER BY
        _t.geom::GEOGRAPHY <-> <input_geom>::GEOGRAPHY
      LIMIT
        1
    ),
    <radius_in_meter>
  )
;
```

---

I strongly recommend to get familiar with distance units and index usage; related posts with further links and info:

- [PostGIS, closest point to another point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/postgis-closest-point-to-another-point/401429#401429)
- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Finding nearest neighbor for each point in the same table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/finding-nearest-neighbor-for-each-point-in-the-same-table/287810#287810)

Comment: @AsandaLamba did this solve your question/problem? If so, consider accepting the answer. If not, what issues are you facing?